# Добавить в скрипт сохранение данных в локальном хранилище браузера

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт динамического счетчика, нужно доработать код таким образом, чтобы происходило сохранение данных в локальном хранилище браузера. Т.е чтобы после обновления страницы счетчик не слетал.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var n=114; //начальное значение
 
  pollDOM ();
    
  function pollDOM () {
      if (n>0) {
       n=n+randomInteger(1, 1); //диапозон случайных прибовляемых цифр
        if (n<0) n=0;`введите сюда код`
        $('#mytime').text(n);
       setTimeout(pollDOM, 30000);  //задержка перед прибавлением в милисекундах
      }
  }    
 
  function randomInteger(min, max) {
     let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
      return Math.round(rand);
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: попробуйте использовать `localStorage`?

Comment: Я знаю, что надо localStorage, я незнаю как его приписать?

Comment: Объяснил в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$(function () {
  // получаем значение из localStorage, если оно там есть
  var n = +localStorage.getItem('counter') || 114; //начальное значение

  pollDOM();

  function pollDOM() {
    if (n > 0) {
      n = n + randomInteger(1, 1); //диапозон случайных прибовляемых цифр
      if (n < 0) n = 0;
      $('#mytime').text(n);
      // сохранение значения в localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('counter', n);
      setTimeout(pollDOM, 30000);  //задержка перед прибавлением в милисекундах
    }
    
  }

  function randomInteger(min, max) {
    let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
    return Math.round(rand);
  };
});
```

Для того, чтобы изменить значение в `localStorage`, используйте `localStorage.setItem`, а для того, чтобы получить значение, используйте `localStorage.getItem`.

Подробнее про `localStorage`: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage.

Comment: Нет, не работает, добавляются только единицы после обновления страницы

Comment: Как вы запускаете?

Comment: @PetLinux, а вы учли, что `localStorage.getItem` возвращает СТРОКУ?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, извините, исправил.

Comment: @ИринаАбдрахманова, проверьте, работает ли сейчас.

Comment: @PetLinux да работает, спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!!!!

Comment: Бывает перескакивает в меньшую сторону, т.е например было 345, при обновлении страницы стало 340, потом при еще обновлении стало 346

Comment: @ИринаАбдрахманова можете, пожалуйста, принять ответ?